# Comparing logistic model predictive ability with same sample but different IV

Tags: logistic, aic, overfitting

I would like to compare two logit models. Both models use the exact same sample (1 - pass a test and 0 - fail a test).  The first model will use one IV (IV1) and the second model will use a different IV (IV).

When I run the model with both IV1 and IV2, only IV1 is has a significant coefficient.

I have also run the models with IV1 and IV2 separately.  The AIC is lower for the model with the IV1.  Can I use the lower AIC to conclude that the model with IV1 has a better predictive ability than the model with just IV2 (in addition to the fact that it has a better count R2, adjusted count R2, etc.?)

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: This has been covered in depth in many places on this site.  Search for "compare logistic."

Comment: Do you have a specific link you could offer - it would be much appreciated. I searched the previous threats, but, could not find an answer to my specific question.

Comment: Thanks for any information - it is very much appreciated